# OnscreenDiv error while using tinytest

Tags: meteor

I am following the discover meteor example to create a tinytest for errors. But there is a problem in the errors_tests.js file in the block:

```
//render the template
OnscreenDiv(Spark.render(function() {
    return Template.meteorErrors();
}));
```

When I run the test it fails with the message "OnscreenDiv is not defined".

I know that Meteor uses Blaze as the templating engine. My question is it a custom defined function, or is this an old example? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It's probably an old example - Spark is the predecessor of Blaze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem. It is an old example.

When I run Meteor 1.1.X, I change that block with:

```
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.meteorErrors), document.body);
```

and it work.